# java.lang.AssertionError: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert:

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I m using Spring Mvc Jpa mysql in my project.
 I had some problems with my dependencies to solve that I was obligate to create i new project and copy the code from the old one with other dependencies.in the first time I forgot the make create in :

```
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

I got some errors, then I'v change it to create, my tables were created correcly; and then i'v change it to update.but when I try to insert data from form or with class for junit test i got these error. To know that the first project insert data correctly I've changed nothing just my data base name.

My applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

     <bean id="dataSource"     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">     </property>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elearning"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
     <property name="password" value=""></property>
   </bean>
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
           <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
       <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
    </list>
   </property>
         <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
      </bean>
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory"    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UP_LR"></property>

   </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
       </bean>
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
     <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
     <bean id="dao" class="com.pattern.learning.dao.ElearningDaoImpl"></bean>
   <bean id="metier"  class="com.pattern.learning.metier.LearningMetierImp">
     <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

My persistence.xml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
      <persistence-unit name="UP_LR" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

and the error:

```
       javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.pattern.learning.entites.Specialite]
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:219)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.persist(Unknown Source)
com.pattern.learning.dao.ElearningDaoImpl.ajouterSpecialite(ElearningDaoImpl.java:19)
com.pattern.learning.metier.LearningMetierImp.ajouterSpecialite(LearningMetierImp.java:67)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.ajouterSpecialite(Unknown Source)
com.pattern.learning.controller.AdminSpecialiteController.saveSpe(AdminSpecialiteController.java:55)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

     cause mère 

   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.pattern.learning.entites.Specialite]
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:131)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:87)
org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:38)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:618)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:592)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:596)
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:213)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.persist(Unknown Source)
com.pattern.learning.dao.ElearningDaoImpl.ajouterSpecialite(ElearningDaoImpl.java:19)
com.pattern.learning.metier.LearningMetierImp.ajouterSpecialite(LearningMetierImp.java:67)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.ajouterSpecialite(Unknown Source)
com.pattern.learning.controller.AdminSpecialiteController.saveSpe(AdminSpecialiteController.java:55)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Specialite class:
         package com.pattern.learning.entites;

```
     import java.io.Serializable;
     import java.util.Collection;

     import javax.persistence.Entity;
     import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
     import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
     import javax.persistence.Id;
     import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
     import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
     import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
     import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
     import javax.persistence.Table;
     @Entity
        @Table(name="Specialite")
  public class Specialite implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long idspeciality;
 private String nomspecialite;
 private String desciption;
 private byte[]  photo;
 private String nomphoto;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="specialite")
 private Collection<Cours> cours;
 @ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="Spe_user",joinColumns= 
       @JoinColumn(name="idspeciality"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="iduser"))
 private Collection<User> users;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="specialite")
 private Collection<Competance> competances;

public Collection<Competance> getCompetances() {
    return competances;
}
public void setCompetances(Collection<Competance> competances) {
    this.competances = competances;
}
public Long getIdspeciality() {
    return idspeciality;
}
public void setIdspeciality(Long idspeciality) {
    this.idspeciality = idspeciality;
}
public String getNomspecialite() {
    return nomspecialite;
}
public void setNomspecialite(String nomspecialite) {
    this.nomspecialite = nomspecialite;
}
public String getDesciption() {
    return desciption;
}
public void setDesciption(String desciption) {
    this.desciption = desciption;
}
public byte[] getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}
public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
public String getNomphoto() {
    return nomphoto;
}
public void setNomphoto(String nomphoto) {
    this.nomphoto = nomphoto;
}
public Collection<Cours> getCours() {
    return cours;
}
public void setCours(Collection<Cours> cours) {
    this.cours = cours;
}
public Collection<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
public void setUsers(Collection<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
public Specialite(String nomspecialite, String desciption, byte[] photo,
        String nomphoto) {
    super();
    this.nomspecialite = nomspecialite;
    this.desciption = desciption;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.nomphoto = nomphoto;
}
public Specialite() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



 }
```

please I really need your help

Comment: post your DTO in your OP.Hibernate cannot write to your table correctly, you may have some issue on the mapping.

Comment: specialite class @JasonZ

Comment: I was able to insert with the same code iv just changed my data base to a new one

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you haven't specified the entity classes in the `persistance.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
  <persistence-unit name="UP_LR" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.pattern.learning.entites.Specialite</class>
        <class>com.pattern.learning.entites.Entity1</class>
        <class>com.pattern.learning.entites.Entity1</class>

        <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
           <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
           <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>

 </persistence-unit>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found it i forgot to add spring core dependency. thanks for your help

Comment: @KaoutarLaz: where did you specify the entity classes ? Not in persistance.xml?

Comment: I specify that in the applicationContext.xml that's work